# Read JSON Error from HTTPCookie in Swift not working

Tags: json, swift, unicode

I'm trying to read a string serialized json object from a http cookie. The string looks like this

```
"{\"status\": 400\054 \"code\": \"14040\"\054 \"links\": {\"self\": \"\"}\054 \"title\": \"Conflicting Email\"}"
```

So there are unicode entities in it like: `\054` which is just a comma `,`

When i try to convert the string into a json object like this

```
if let data = cookieValue.data(using: .ascii) {
    do {
        let obj = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String : AnyObject]
        // print("Successfull: \(obj)")
    } catch let error as NSError {
        // print("Cannot convert data to json: \(data)\nError: \(error)")
    }
}
```

It returns me an error saying:

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Invalid escape sequence around character 17.) UserInfo=0x78e586c0 {NSDebugDescription=Invalid escape sequence around character 17.}
```

Character 17 is the location of `\054`.

What do i need to do to convert unicode entities to text?

Comment: Is encoding Unicode or ASCII? They may have some common codes for same characters, but they're different encodings.

Comment: Also, isn't `\054` is parsed as `<null-char>54`? Like "\" escapes only `0`.

Comment: Smells like a JavaScript string literal escape. In JS `\0` could be a null char, or it could be part of a 1–3 digit octal escape. Octal 0o54 is decimal 44 is ASCII comma. Octal escapes are confusing and useless, which is why they (and indeed null escapes) are not part of the JSON standard. Quite why the cookie creating code might have decided to JS-string-literal-escape an already-encoded JSON value is mysterious, but since there is no standard way to encode arbitrary characters into a cookie, they could be doing any crazy thing...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var str2 = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\054", with: ",")
```

That worked for me, this is the code I used for testing.

```
import Foundation

var str = "{\"status\": 400\054 \"code\": \"14040\"\054 \"links\": {\"self\": \"\"}\054 \"title\": \"Conflicting Email\"}"

var str2 = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\054", with: ",")

let data = str2.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)!

do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
    for (key, value) in json {
        print(key)
    }
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Failed to load: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}
```

Comment: This could be one solution in that specific case where only the comma is escaped. But I'm looking for the right way to decode octo escaped chars.